# RecyclerView onClick always returns "No view found for id"

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, fragment

I am trying to open a fragment from another fragment inside recyclerView but every time i select a recyclerViewItem i always get "No view found for id" for the fragment. I tried many solution, but my efforts failed so far.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
ImageCache imageCache;
List<Product> product = new Select().from(Product.class).queryList();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FlowManager.init(getApplicationContext());
    final MyApp app = new MyApp(this);
    imageCache = new ImageCache();

    /**
     *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
     */
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

    /**
     * Lets inflate the very first fragment
     * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
     */
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();

    /**
     * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
     */
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_home) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction hfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                hfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_products) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction pfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                pfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new ProductsFragment()).commit();
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_news) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction nfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                nfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new NewsFragment()).commit();
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_companies) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                cfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new CompaniesFragment()).commit();
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_save_db) {
                app.createDatabase();
                app.setLastUpdatedDate();
                imageCache.imageDownloader(getApplicationContext());
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_update_db) {
                app.updateOutdatedDatabase(app.getLastUpdatedDate());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    /**
     * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
     */
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();


    for (int i = 0; i < product.size(); i++) {
        //Log.i("Name", product.get(i).getProductName());
        Log.i("dasd", product.get(i).getProductImage());
    }
    //app.createDatabase();
    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    /*Picasso.with(this)
            .load(new File(product.get(2).getProductImage()))
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
            .into(imageView);
     */
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        imageCache.imageDownloader(this);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

MyRecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder> {

private ArrayList<HomeObject> mDataset;
private Context context;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
private String[] postTypeRef = new String[] {"Νέα","Κίνδυνοι","Προειδοποιήσεις"};

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, MyClickListener myClickListener) {

    this.context = context;
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}
public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView label;
    TextView company;
    TextView description;
    ImageView imageDrawable;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        company = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        imageDrawable = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v);
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
    this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<HomeObject> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_home_item, parent, false);

    DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getLabel());
    holder.company.setText(mDataset.get(position).getCompany());
    holder.description.setText(mDataset.get(position).getTextDescr());

    if (Arrays.asList(postTypeRef).contains(mDataset.get(position).getLabel())){
        Picasso.with(MyApp.applicationContext).load(mDataset.get(position)
                .imageIDFetch()).into(holder.imageDrawable);
    }
    else{
        Picasso.with(MyApp.applicationContext).load(new File(mDataset.get(position)
                .getImageCached())).into(holder.imageDrawable);
    }

}

public void addItem(HomeObject dataObj, int index) {
    mDataset.add(dataObj);
    notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
    mDataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public interface MyClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}}
```

And last HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private int productsListCounter = 0;
private int postsListCounter = 0;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private static String LOG_TAG = "RecyclerViewActivity";
private Context context;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, null);

    context = container.getContext();
    final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity())
                    .color(Color.rgb(11, 122, 11))
                    .margin(15, 15)
                    .build());
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());

    PreCachingLayoutManager layoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    layoutManager.setExtraLayoutSpace(DeviceUtils.getScreenHeight(getActivity()));

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
                mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((MyRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, " Clicked on Item " + position);
            Fragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.main_activity, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context,this);
        }
    });
}



private ArrayList<HomeObject> getDataSet() {

    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<HomeObject>();
    List<Product> products = new Select().from(Product.class).queryList();
    List<Post> posts = new Select().from(Post.class).queryList();

        for (productsListCounter = 0; productsListCounter<products.size(); productsListCounter++){
            Company companyIDQuery = new Select().from(Company.class)
                    .where(com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.builder.Condition.column(Post$Table.COMPANYID)
                            .eq(posts.get(productsListCounter).getCompanyID())).querySingle();

            HomeObject homeContainer = new HomeObject(
                    "Προίον: " + products.get(productsListCounter).getProductName(),
                    "Εταιρεία : " + companyIDQuery.getCompanyName(),
                    products.get(productsListCounter).getProductDescr(),
                    products.get(productsListCounter).getProductImage(),
                    products.get(productsListCounter).getUpdatedAT());
            results.add(productsListCounter, homeContainer);
        }

        for (postsListCounter = 0; postsListCounter<posts.size(); postsListCounter++){
            PostType postTypeIDQuery = new Select().from(PostType.class)
                    .where(com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.builder.Condition.column(Post$Table.POSTTYPEID)
                            .eq(posts.get(postsListCounter).getPostTypeID())).querySingle();

            Company companyIDQuery = new Select().from(Company.class)
                    .where(com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.builder.Condition.column(Post$Table.COMPANYID)
                            .eq(posts.get(postsListCounter).getCompanyID())).querySingle();

            HomeObject homeContainer = new HomeObject(
                    postTypeIDQuery.getPostTypeDescr(),
                    "Εταιρεία : " + companyIDQuery.getCompanyName(),
                    posts.get(postsListCounter).getPostText(),
                    "",
                    posts.get(postsListCounter).getUpdatedAT());
            results.add(productsListCounter + postsListCounter, homeContainer);
        }

    Collections.sort(results, Collections.reverseOrder());
    return results;
}}
```

So when i click on HomeFragment recyclerViewItem i want to open another fragment with data and position.Also all fragments belong to MainActivity layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main_activity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="Drawer With Swipe Tabs" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    >


    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">
    </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: may this help to get click on RecycleView listitem http://amolsawant88.blogspot.in/2015/08/easy-way-to-highlight-selected-rowitem.html

Comment: I have already done this!! this is not the problem because as you can see i already have implemented onClick. The problem is that i can't open another fragment when i click on RecyclerViewItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you added wrong statement in `HomeFragment` below line

```
transaction.add(R.id.main_activity, fragment);
```

example as below
instead of `R.id.main_activity` add  `R.id.containerView`
it will solve your issue

```
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("city", "city");
                            bundle.putBoolean("demo_access", true);

                            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                            PlantFragment plantFragment = new PlantFragment();
                            plantFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, plantFragment, "temp");
                            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("pref");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after many days i figured it out. On MainActivity i added a method

```
public void onItemClick() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new ProductFragment());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

and just called it from HomeFragment

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((RecyclerViewHomeAdapter) mAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {

            Log.i("onclick", " Clicked on Item " + position);
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onItemClick();

        }
    });
}
```